# load data after dispatch_get_global_queue finish

Tags: swift

well I'm fetching data from internet and this data is similar to be slower

so i have to load it inside dispatch_get_global_queue but on viewDidLoad

but the main problem that if there's collectionView or table it will load while the data is fetching from internet and then collection view for section give me nil , how it's possible to make the collection view load after dispatch_get_global_queue finish

```
import UIKit


class SectionViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTab: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionTitle: UILabel!
    var sectionsPosts:JSON!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var sectionsTap:JSON!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

                    let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
                if let url = NSURL(string: "http://nepraswebsite.com/new_lille/mobile_api/blog/first_tab/1") {
                    if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
                        self.sectionsTap = JSON(data: data)
                    }
                }

                if let newurl = NSURL(string: "http://nepraswebsite.com/new_lille/mobile_api/blog/posts_by_category/" + sections[tapIndex]["Slug"].stringValue + "/1") {
                    if let newdata = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: newurl, options: []) {
                        self.sectionsPosts = JSON(data: newdata)
                    }
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

        }

    }
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return sectionsPosts.count

    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("postsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostsCollectionViewCell


            cellA.postImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: sectionsPosts[indexPath.row]["Image"].stringValue
                ), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "demopic"))
            cellA.postTitle.text = sectionsPosts[indexPath.row]["Title"].stringValue
            return cellA

    }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: sectionsPosts[indexPath.row]["URL"].stringValue
)!)


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `numberOfItemsInSection` needs to know that the background task has not yet finished. One way of doing that is:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sectionPosts?.count ?? 0
    // or
    return sectionsPosts == nil ? 0 : sectionsPosts.count
}
```

When the load has finished, you then set this variable and call reloadData to display.

However, there are a couple of problems still. Firstly, `reloadData` needs to be called on the main queue, along the lines of:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
 })
```

Secondly, Apple recommends using `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` (on `NSURLSession`) instead of `contentsOfURL:`. This will run the task in a background thread for you, and provide a completion handler for your response code. You can find this recommendation under the `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` section in the NSData documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:).

Comment: `return sectionPosts?.count ?? 0`

Comment: @nhgrif yeah I hear you. Old habits die hard.